# Is a question about ethics on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

I consider asking a question about using the work of someone else, and I wonder if it's on-topic or not. It's about ethics and etiquette.

I've used full work/libraries written by other people, and it's quite easy: *respect the attribution as asked*.

The work I think of is actually a codepen, no mention of attribution in the code, no comment, nothing specifically asked. I've tested the code, found it useful, and have modified it. *A lot*. Basically, I kept 15% (tops), and wrote my own scripts.

It's a website for a sports association (NPO) and I do this *pro bono*, it's a small shop online for their (tee-)shirts (1 page, 1 cart, 1 checkout, 1 contact, 1 about us). I needed a simple shopping cart (based on localStorage, no DB), I found a model on codepen. I've used the idea, a couple of lines/function, but modified the core of the script(s). But I did gain some time (and ideas) for sure.

I think like tagging my work as: "*Based on xxx*" or "*Inspired by xxx*". Is there good practice/etiquette for this and is it discussed here?

Comment: How is this related to your website?

Comment: I'm currently working for a sports association (NPO) *pro bono*, it's a small shop online for their (tee-)shirts (1 page, 1 cart, 1 checkout, 1 contact, 1 about us). I needed a simple shopping cart (based on localStorage, no DB), I found a model on codepen. I've used the idea, a couple of lines/function, but modified the core of the script(s). But I did gain some time (and ideas) for sure. This needs to be said, but how?...